# Can a /44 (global) IPv6 subnet be routed on the internet

Tags: ipv6

I read that the smallest internet routable subnet in ipv6 is a /48.

I am a bit confused with the word smallest here, does it mean:

1. 44 Is smaller than 48
2. 44 Is bigger than 48 because it has more IP addresses, so everything with smaller subnets than /48 is not internet routable (i.e. /52, /56, ...)

Basically I ask because I want to know if a /44 is routable to the internet or not, in case you need more than 15 sites for a business.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> smallest internet routable subnet in ipv6 is a /48.

"Smallest" in this case refers to host count, i.e. your case 2) is correct. This means that /44 is globally routable because it is "larger" than /48, because it has more addresses available, i.e. more bits left for the host suffix.

But since the number after "/" indicates prefix length in bits, another good term would be **'shorter'**. Prefixes that are /48 or shorter are globally routable (i.e. will be accepted by ISPs via BGP); longer prefixes are not. Because /44 is shorter than /48, it is globally routable.

Summary:

- /44 is larger than /48 because the network contains more possible addresses.
- /44 is shorter than /48 because the prefix has fewer bits.
- Alternatively, think of the "/" as a division operator: 1/44 is larger than 1/48.

Comment: Thank you for this well constructed awnser!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in IP terminology, *smaller* means fewer addresses per subnet.

- A /25 is smaller than a /24 (because 128 vs 256 addresses)
- A /48 is smaller than a /44 (because 2^80 vs 2^84 addresses)

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 addresses use 128 bits to represent an address.
The second half of the address (least significant 64 bits) is always used for hosts only.
The addressing scheme looks like this:

[image]

The 16 bits allocated for subnets allow 65536 subnets. If you use some of these bits
for the prefix you will have less than 16 bits left, so fewer possible subnets.
So the larger the prefix, fewer/smaller subnets are possible.

The following table will give an idea of how this works:

[image]

It can be seen here that `/64` prefix allows only one subnet, so is the smallest
subnet but with the largest prefix.

The prefix `/48` is the smallest prefix, but since it allows the biggest
number of 65536 subnets, it is the largest.

The prefix of `/44` is even larger, but will not usually be allocated to
organizations that are clients of ISPs.

Useful references:

- [How does IPv6 subnetting work and how does it differ from IPv4 subnetting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/426183/how-does-ipv6-subnetting-work-and-how-does-it-differ-from-ipv4-subnetting)
- [Networking Concepts IPv6 Subnetting](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/book/network/ipv6-subnets.html)
- [IPv6 - Subnetting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ipv6/ipv6_subnetting.htm)